# Comparing rates of different populations given as percentages instead of raw numbers

Tags: weighted-sampling

Here's an example of what I mean.
500
Consider a hypothetical game played by members of a population of unknown size.

1. Group A is 13% of the whole population and scores 500  points in a game.
2. Group B is 85% of the population but scores only 250 points in the game.
3. The remaining 2% is a smaller group I am not concerned with.

I think group A scores at a rate that is approximately 8 or 10 times higher **after controlling for population size*.

How would I set up an equation to obtain rates for each population and compare them?

Thanks.

Comment: what kind of rate are you talking about?